# Two stacked dynamic height labels in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am trying to have two labels stacked in a UITableViewCell. I have AutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight set on my tableView.
[image]

I want the cells to show up stacked, with their dynamic heights if they both have content.

If only one has content, I would like it to be centered in the cell, or rather have the cell collapse to only show that label.

[image]

I have tried every constraint combo I can think of, but usually the labels either do not expand, or I end up with filler space where the label should be.

If the label has no text, I am setting `label.text = ""`.

I am calling `sizeToFit()` on the labels each time I set the text.

What is the correct constraint combo? Here is what I currently have to start with.
[image]
[image]

Comment: use stack view ?

Comment: Why is the constraint between labels @ 750 priority? Also, did you set `numberOfLines` to `0` on both of them?

Answer (score 3):

- you have to make two labels with leading, trailing, top and bottom constrains and don't add height constrains
- make the number of lines for labels = 0
- check the title label and from size inspector menu click on the vertical content hugging priority to be 250 not 251 as shown in the screen

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgCQf.png)

- in the viewController connect your tableview and add these lines

  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using StackViews in iOS,

in the Storyboard Select your both Labels and embed them inside a `UIStackView`

one of the benefits if you declared a good constraints it should automatically handle the requested behavior.

[image]

I recommend this tutorial to get started with `UIStackView`  [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/508-uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is `UIStackView`.

If still you want to go with `UILabel` you can try one more thing:

[image]

Setting `label.text = ""` will decrease the height of label but the constraint for distance between the labels will not make the label in centre.

For that add a referencing outlet of distance constraint and set it :

```
distanceConstraint.constant = 0
```

programatically while setting the `label.text = ""`.

This will set the label with data in centre.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What solved for me was, "Better solution is UIStackView." I did not realize UIStackView could do this task so easily. Note: I did set the leading/top/trailing/bottom margins and no height which may help too.